# Android Reading array into TextView

Tags: android, arrays, textview

I have this piece of code. I am trying to read elements of the array and display it in a textview in android.  The code displays the correct thing if I just use a print statement plain java instead of the android sdk. I've been trying to figure it out for a while now. Any help?

```
     package com.example.trivia;

      import java.io.File;
      import java.io.IOException;
      import java.util.Random;
      import java.util.Scanner;

      import android.app.Activity;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.os.CountDownTimer;
      import android.widget.Button;
      import android.widget.TextView;



public class PlayActivity extends Activity {
  String [][]array;
  String [][] questionsArray;
  int []playindexArray = new int[50];
  TextView timer, questions;
  Button answerA, answerB, answerC, answerD;
  String show = "Buttons and Question";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
    timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer); 
    questions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questions);
    answerA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
    answerB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonB);
    answerC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonC);
    answerD = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonD);



//countdowntimer
    CountDownTimer count = new CountDownTimer(32000, 1000) {
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             timer.setText("TIME REMAINING: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

         }
         public void onFinish() {
             timer.setText("TIME UP!");
         }
      };
      count.start();
              try {
        readCSV();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }


  public void readCSV() throws IOException{
        array = new String[117][6];
        String delimiter = ",";
        int row =0;
        File file = new File("questions1.csv");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);     

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) 
        {
           String line = sc.nextLine();
           String [] temp = line.split(delimiter);
           for(int i = 0; i< temp.length; i++){
              array[row][i] = temp[i];   
            }
           row++;
         }
        questionsArray = new String[117][6];
        questionsArray = array;
        questions.setText(questionsArray[0][2]);
        }
```

Comment: There's no TextView in your code. Show us what you've tried in regards to that.

Comment: what are you looking for? how to create textview? or how to show in textview? if the later one is what you want then how you want to show in textview? in multi line?

Comment: @pzyren  also, where is your print statement?, show the full and relevant  code.

Comment: Please post your  full code...

Comment: @StinePike  the textview is called questions.   does not show up in the textview when I run.

Comment: from where are you calling the readcsv method

Comment: @StinePike I call the readCSV inside onCreate method. is that wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `TextView` in your code. Nor `setText` method. The simplest `TextView` works like this

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_of_your_textview);
text.setText("your text");
```

show the relevant code that you have tried first. then show the error you are getting. this will speed up the process of you getting what you are looking for.

Comment: there are clearly two textViews in there timer and questions refer to class declaration. and there is also the initialization inside OnCreate method.

Comment: yes I can see you have updated the code. Now my question is about the readCSV method. from where are you calling it? if this method is supposed to fetch the string you are trying to display then it should be called from somewhere. something like this questions.setText(readCSV(q)); where in you are calling the method and the return type of the method is in the form of a string. something like this. right now i dont see you calling this method from anywhere in this code.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to reply. I called it at the end of onCreate. the code itself actually works because if I run it without the SDK it prints what I need. but when I call it in onCreate, it doesn't show up in the textView. I'm not sure If I'm not supposed to be calling it in onCreate.